# Concat multiple Videos using FFmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, concatenation

So, I gonna concat multiple video files with various ***RESOLUTION*** into one file.
Thus, I need to set the start time and end time of each video.
I want senior's help.
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this can help? Seems to be the same issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18141055/ffmpeg-commands-to-concatenate-different-type-and-resolution-videos-into-1-video

Comment: Thanks. But in this post, I have to use n line commands....I want 1-line command.

Comment: See [How to concatenate videos in ffmpeg with different attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57367243/)